# Create new LaTeX environment

Tags: math-mode, packages, environments, mdframed, tufte

I'm writing a text using the document-class *tufte-book* and I want to create some new environments in order to do example and insights. Until now I used the package mdframed, but I noticed that with that package I can't use commands like `\marginnote`, `\footnote` and so on in those environment because they create a sort of minipage in which the command `\marginnote` can't be used (a tufte-book problem) and footnotes aren't numbered but they are shown with a letter (this creates an error during compiling). Do you know any other packages that allow me to create environment in a similar way? The code I used to create those envirnoments is

```
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{linecolor=gray,linewidth=1pt,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=mygray,
innertopmargin=\topskip}\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle,
  nobreak
]{example}{Example}[chapter]
```

and

```
\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{%
hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
innertopmargin=0.4em,
innerbottommargin=0.4em,
innerrightmargin=0.7em,
rightmargin=0.7em,
innerleftmargin=1.7em,
leftmargin=0.7em,
middlelinewidth=.2em,
linecolor=black,
}
\newmdenv[
  style=warning,
  innerbottommargin=10pt,
  linewidth=0.5pt,
  ntheorem=false
]{insight}
```

Here an example of TeX code I used

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{linecolor=gray,
linewidth=1pt,
frametitlerule=true,
frametitlebackgroundcolor=mygray,
innertopmargin=\topskip}
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle,
nobreak]{example}{Example}[chapter]
\mdfdefinestyle{warning}{%
hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
innertopmargin=0.4em,
innerbottommargin=0.4em,
innerrightmargin=0.7em,
rightmargin=0.7em,
innerleftmargin=1.7em,
leftmargin=0.7em,
middlelinewidth=.2em,
linecolor=black,
}
\newmdenv[
style=warning,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
linewidth=0.5pt,
ntheorem=false
]{insight} 
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
 This is an example. \marginnote{Example name}
\end{example}
\begin{insight}
 \marginnote{Main argument of the insight}This is an insight \footnote{Notes about the insight}
\end{insight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: side notes and footnotes in such boxes are difficult. Use the tcolorbox package. It tries hard to support this. But read its documentation to understand restrictions and how to use such notes.

Comment: I tried to use tcolorbox package, but also with the environments created with it I can't use \sidenotes and \footnotes